# How frequently should PhD students update their advisor?

Tags: phd, advisor, supervision

I'm a 1st year phd student in math. My advisor adopts a more ambiguous meeting policy that I approach him whenever I want to talk. So I was sending him long emails on a biweekly basis with updates of what I read and thought about in that duration, out of my own initiative. Of course, a lot of it is not substantial progress and probably doesn't even worth reporting. I do this because the actual meeting is sporadic and the frequency is definitely below once per several months. So I feel that I should update him on a regular basis. My advisor didn't say stop sending the updates but just stopped responding to them. I guess it is kind of annoying seeing a lot of stuff from your students without actual breakthrough. Before I ask him anything, I just wonder what would be the norm of phd student updating their advisors regarding frequency and whether they should update without any actual progress.

Comment: You should ask other students of your advisor or in your program. I think the consensus on this site would be anywhere from once weekly to once a month. Once per several months is low, IMO, especially for a first year

Comment: I work full-time and am a CS PhD student (work and research overlap). Since I make less progress than full-time PhD students, I usually send a weekly or bi-weekly email letting my advisor know I'm still doing stuff and meet when needed. Regarding your emails, professors get a lot of it. It may be worth condensing your emails to the important updates/questions and use the meetings for things that are more easily verbally discussed.

Comment: I think it depends on many variables and the field. I see you are from Maths. But even though, is hard to think of an answer. We were basically on everyday contact.

Comment: Even as a postdoc, I update my PI weekly. Even if the update is "no progress this week". It helps build a good working dynamic and can show the advisor if you are stuck or need more help.

Comment: As often as a new version of your advisor is published.

Comment: It completely depends - you will get 10 different answers - speak to your supervisor and iterate on a solution that works for YOU!

Answer (score 8):

It depends on your situation. I meet with each of my students once a week via Zoom. When I was a student, I met with my advisor rarely. I only gave him finished results.

Comment: You want to keep your meetings fruitful for both, concise, and ending on a positive note.

Comment: @Aruralreader: Thanks for an advice.